# How to add and delete "rows" in an accordion in jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I simply want for users to be able to add and delete rows at their own will.

A quick trial of the jsFiddle will show that it works for rows that are already in the html but any rows that are added after (using append), can't be deleted in the same way.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshmason11/4KxSS/) - The easiest way to explain/show what's going on

```
    $('.removeBtn').click(function(){
        $(this).parent('div').next('div').andSelf().remove();
});
$('#add_item').click(function(){
    $('#accordion').append('<div><a href="#">Round 2</a><div class="removeBtn">x</div></div><div><div class="title">Question 1</div></div>').accordion('destroy').accordion();
});
```

The code above shows how I am attempting to add/remove the rows

And here's the **HTML**:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div><a href="#">Round 1</a>
    <div class="removeBtn">x</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="title">Question 1</div>
  </div>

</div>
<div id="add_item">Add</div>
```

Comment: Since the delete element wasn't in the dom on page load, it never bound the click event. Delegate the click event on the parent element $('#accordion').on('click', removeBtn, function { ... });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation since the buttons are added dynamically

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function(){
    $(this).parent('div').next('div').andSelf().remove();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LdmTN/)